# How to install pyPgSQL.PgSQL on Mac or Ubuntu?

Tags: python, postgresql, twisted

I'm writing a segment of code connected postgreSQL using python below:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
import pyPgSQL.PgSQL


def getSites():
    return dbpool.runQuery("select * from TypeTable")


def printResult(l):
    for item in l:
        print item


dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('pyPgSQL.PgSQL', user="joe", \
    password="zjz666", host="192.168.10.50", database="collectiondb")
getSites().addCallback(printResult)
reactor.callLater(4, reactor.stop)
reactor.run()
```

Then I run it an get an error that `ImportError: No module named pyPgSQL.PgSQL`

Strangely, I can't find any answer to install it???What can I do?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try this `apt-get install python-pgsql` . Check here http://pypgsql.sourceforge.net/pypgsql-faq.html

Comment: I have tried and got an error`E: Package 'python-pgsql' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Which OS did you try and what is your python version?

Comment: Python 2.7.6 & ubuntu14.04

Comment: What does `apt-get update &&  apt-get install python-pgsql` output?

Comment: `E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`